Dealing with I/O exceptions beyond OSError
I have an endless program that needs to write to daily log files. Below is basically my Message class that opens a file at startup and closes/opens a new file daily. Now I'm testing for error handling, as the program should not die even if it can't write logs. For example, the file system fills up. Most normal I/O errors are OSError, and this handles those.
If at startup the initial file can't be opened, I get this exception

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

because the log object can't be created. I then try to log.write to a None object with no write routine. A good log open creates a <class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>. Is there a way to initialize log to a dummy TextIOWrapper? And would that gain me anything?
Because if you do write to a closed file handle you get this exception

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

I'm baffled as to why this is not an OSError. So I at least have to add ValueError to my exception list.
class Message:
    log_date = f"{datetime.now():%Y%m%d}"
    log_file = log_date + '.log'
    try:
        log = open(log_file, 'a')
        log.write(f"{log_file} opened\n")
        log.flush()
    except OSError as err:
        errno, strerror = err.args
        print(f"I/O Error with {log_file}; {strerror}")

    def print(msg: str):
        today = f"{datetime.now():%Y%m%d}"
        try:
            if today != Message.log_date:
                Message.log.close()
                Message.log_date = today
                Message.log_file = today + '.log'
                Message.log = open(Message.log_file, 'a')
                Message.log.write(f"{Message.log_file} opened\n")
            Message.log.write(f"{msg}\n")
            Message.log.flush()
        except OSError as err:
            errno, strerror = err.args
            print(f"I/O Error with {Message.log_file}; {strerror}")


It seems like your question is why the exception has the type it does. There isn't a good way to answer that, because it's up to the language designers to have made the decision. If there was something else you wanted to know (such as how to handle multiple exception types at once), that wasn't clear. If "Is there a way to initialize log to a dummy TextIOWrapper?" is the main question, that should be refined and highlighted (and please assume it can be done).

It's a ValueError because the value of Message.log.closed can be used to "predict" that the write would fail before you even try any I/O or OS interaction.

Please correct your code, since it has code outside of its methods.

It is better to use TimedRotatingFileHandler and set its interval to one day (or set it to roll over midnight) and set backupCount=30 for example. Since it delete old logs automatically (but you have log for last 1 month in our example)), chance of disk filling up will be lower. You can use NullHandler on error.
